# Let the smallest positive integer with six positive odd integer divisors and twelve positive even integer divisors, be n. What is the unit digit of n?

Tags: number-theory

Let the smallest positive integer with six positive odd integer divisors and twelve positive even integer divisors, be n. What is the unit digit of n?

I am not able to get an idea what the question is saying...

Comment: https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2000_AIME_II_Problems/Problem_4

Comment: Show $5$ must be a factor and the number is even, so ______

Comment: 0 is the answer

Comment: Divisors of 180 are: 1, 3, 5, 9, 15, 45; and 2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 18, 20, 30, 36, 60, 90, 180.

Comment: @almagest Shouldn't there be a 7 in the odd divisors and hence no 45?